# Java queue using linkedlist

Tags: java, spring, linked-list, queue

I am struggling with an assignment. The goal is to fill in blanks in a queue implementation using linked list and write an output. All the code with stars (****code****) are those blanks that I filled, some of them very likely wrongly filled and - I don't fully understand why.

If someone could point me in the right direction, fix the code or explain what did I fill wrong and why, I would be grateful.

Thank you,
Timmy

Edit: Please find the enclosed assignment in link [link](http://postimg.org/image/sh1bo2ssr/)

```
public class DoubleQueue {
public class QueueEmptyException extends RuntimeException{};

private **class** Node{
    double num;
    Node next = null;
    Node (**double** num) {**this**.num = **num**;}
}

private Node head = null;

public void push(double num){
    Node tmp = **new** Node(**num**);
    tmp.**next** = head;
    head = **num**;     
}

public double pop() throws QueueEmptyException {
    if (**num** == null) throw new **QueueEmptyException**(){
    Node node = head;
    if(node.next == null){
        head = null;
        return node.**next**;
    }
    while (node.next.**next** != null)
        **node** = **node**.next;
    }
    double ret = aux.next.**next**;
    aux.next=null;
    return ret;
    }
}


DoubleQueue queue = new DoubleQueue();
queue.push(17);
queue.push(23);
queue.push(15);
System.out.println(queue.pop());
System.out.println(queue.pop());
System.out.println(queue.pop());
```

What is the console output?
1.  _____
2.  _____
3.  _____

Comment: Does it compile? Does it run? Is there an error message?

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing a class declared like that... ???

Comment: I forgot to read your explanation a little deeper.  So are you trying to build a linked list?

Comment: Why are you opening a code block after `throw new **QueueEmptyException**()` ?

Comment: You have added in some bits that are contradictory to your assignment. You should take them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few of the mistakes which I could point out are:

1) `head = **num**;`  ->  `head = **temp**;`

Because you are pointing the head to the latest value inserted.

2) `if (**num** == null)`  ->  `if (**head** == null)`

You have to check whether the node object is null or not.

3) `return node.**next**` -> `return node.**num**`

Since the return type is `double` you need to return the number inside the object.

4) `double ret = aux.next.**num**;` -> `double ret = node.next.**num**;`

Again, you have to return the first element which was pushed inside the queue.

Output of the following code would be:

`17 23 15`